# MySQL paginated retrieval of the data avoiding race conditions

Tags: mysql, database

My service is clustered and I am running several instances of it.
I need to collect all entities in the paginated fashion and push them into the caching layer (Redis).
While doing so on one application server, an application that is running on server #2 can already be making the changes.

Those paginated calls to db will be fetching 1000 items at one call.
Now, since I want to prevent modifications while retrieval is ongoing, how do I achieve that?

Can I use `SELECT FOR UPDATE` mechanism even though I am not updating anything in this transaction, but only fetch the data in a paginated fashion?

Comment: What issue are you trying to avoid here, because likely as not there is not one to avoid. You are using a DBMS not access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it were one app instance with multiple threads, you could use a critical section. But that doesn't work for a cluster of app instances.

I implemented this for a service a couple of months ago. The app is deployed in several instances. These instances don't communicate with each other, so they can't coordinate directly. But they all connect to the same MySQL database.

What I did was use the [GET_LOCK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/locking-functions.html#function_get-lock) builtin function of MySQL.

When a routine wants exclusive access, it calls `GET_LOCK('mylock', 0)`. This returns immediately, with a **true** value if it acquired the lock, or a **false** value if the lock was already held by some other client. That tells the client app whether it is the "winner" or not.

If a client is not the winner, then it calls `GET_LOCK('mylock', -1)` which means wait indefinitely. It does this because the winner is working on whatever it needs to do in the critical section.

When the winner finishes, it must call `RELEASE_LOCK('mylock')`. This unblocks the clients who were waiting. They now know that the work of the critical section is done, and they can feel free to read the contents of the cache or whatever else they need to do.

Also remember that the client who were waiting on `GET_LOCK('mylock', -1)` need to call `RELEASE_LOCK('mylock')` immediately, because once they stopped waiting, they actually acquired the lock themselves.

This design allows a single lock coordinator (MySQL) to be used by multiple clients. It implements *pessimistic* locking, without needing to rely on locking any table or set of rows.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your elaborate reply! I do appreciate it.

I wonder what happens with the lock that you  have acquired if suddenly one of the application nodes crashes while holding the lock. 
You do not mention timeouts.
Isn't there a risk that the data could be kept hostage forever?

Comment: If an app crashes, its MySQL session terminates, and that releases any locks and rolls back any transaction it had. Other clients who were waiting on that lock are served in the order they arrived.